# Three.js: tesselated cube looks tiled

Tags: three.js

The tesselated cube:

```js
var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(50, 3, 50, 4, 1, 4);
for (var i=0; i<48; i++) {
   geometry.faces[i].color.setHex(0xA2D3AA);
}
```

looks tiled. How to remove gaps between tiles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `CanvasRenderer` set `material.overdraw = 0.5;` -- or a number between 0 and 1. (It used to be a boolean.)

three.js. r.60